# send image to whatsapp xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

How to send an image from the phone's memory to WhatsApp ?

code send string

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           string phoneNumberWithCountryCode = "88167xxxxxxx";
            string message = "Hallo";
           StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView,
                             Uri.Parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNumberWithCountryCode + "&text=" + message)));
        }
```

Comment: Do you want it to be Whatsapp specific or do you want general deep linking!

Comment: Whatsapp specific

Comment: So what you want is from your app when you share something it should directly open whatsapp's share screen?

Comment: So what you want is from your app when you share something it should directly open whatsapp's share screen? yes